# base url changed after clicking any option angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJS. I am running a program which after first loading shows a base link for ex: 
`www.example.com/ex/index.html?token=1234` (this is right),

but when i click plan button it displays:  www.example.com/ex/plan

but i want the link like this: `www.example.com/ex/index.html?token=1234/plan`

Can anyone please help ?

thanks

Comment: Change the path in the button click listener function?

Comment: my hashbang mode also not working, so i dont see index.html in path. what should i do?

Comment: The hashbang might be gone due to html5mode being on. Maybe you should start with a blank angular app, and then add your stuff in, one by one.

Comment: This url doesn't look like an appropriate use of SPA routing. I'm guessing you probably want something more like `/index.html?token=1234#/plan`, but I'd ask if there is a reason you need to url to change when you click the button.

Comment: yes, Cris, you are right. But, i dont want to change the link, unfortunately its changing automatically.I can see the chnaged link like this : www.example.com/ex/plan

Comment: anchors will pass through the router. if you don't want buttons to have any affect on the url, use `<button>` and not `<a>`.